# How to verify RSA signatures in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptography, rsa

I have a ReactJS application that should be able to verify signatures with a given RSA public key like the Web Crypto API it does with subtle and import_key etc.
Does any one knows if there exist such a library or how to use the Web Crypto API in react directly? I searched a lot, but I wasn't able to find a working example for me. Maybe I missed something.

I tried before the @trust/webcrypto library and installed it with npm.

This is the code that I tried before:

```
const crypto = require('@trust/webcrypto');

function base64decode(str) {
    let buffer = Buffer.from(str, 'base64');
    return new Uint8Array(buffer.buffer.slice(buffer.byteOffset, buffer.byteOffset + buffer.byteLength));
}

function importRsaPublicKey(pem) {
    const binaryDer = base64decode(pem);
    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        binaryDer,
        {
            name: "RSA-PSS",
            hash: "SHA-256",
        },
        true,
        ["verify"]
    );
}
```

The RSA public key is given as a base64 string encoded in ASN.1 DER format.
As an example: `MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAimHHeNG9QnA7aMSjefJzMKfP...4XqwIDAQAB`

My first problem is already to import it correctly.
The signing is maybe already solved, when I have a working library.

When I try the code above I get the following error in my ReactJS application: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module '../algorithms/RSA-PSS'`

I searched for the problem and it seems that I am not able to use it in react that is why I asked if someone knows a library which is working in react to import a RSA public key and is able to verify a signed message with a given signature.

The second library that I tried was `@peculiar/webcrypto`, but that seems also not to work.

The code that I tried:

```
const { Crypto } = require("@peculiar/webcrypto");
const crypto = new Crypto();

function importRsaPublicKey(pem) {
    const binaryDer = base64decode(pem);
    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "pkcs8",
        binaryDer,
        {
            name: "RSA-PSS",
            hash: "SHA-256",
        },
        true,
        ["verify"]
    );
}
```

This raises the error of: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Data does not match to PrivateKeyInfo ASN1 schema.`

The public key is definitely in ASN.1 DER encoding, but it is a public key and not a private key. I don't need the private key in my setting.

Comment: Just FYI: this question doesn't sound like it's specific to React. Also, please post code you've tried and describe how it failed. (also, asking for software recommendations is OT here)

Comment: Ok. Let me edit my question to explain it a bit more.

Comment: I took a look at the library and noticed it's for nodeJS, i.e. is a backend library. React code runs on the frontend though.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for this to mention. I didn't noticed it. I also updated my question with a code example what I did before.

Comment: @ChrisG I added also my second try with a different library that doesn't fit for my use case. Do you maybe know which library fits maybe?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/verify

Comment: If you want to verify, why do you use `sign` as key usage? Also, `pkcs8` is a format of a private key, for a public key it would be rather `spki`, check e.g. [this](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsa-pss---importkey) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#subjectpublickeyinfo_import).

Comment: @Topaco thank you for your response. The "sign" was only a typo, but it doesn't let me import the key anyway.

Comment: @ChrisG the problem is that I am not able to use "SubtleCrypto" directly or maybe I missed how to used in react. Do you know how to use it directly in react? When I use window.crypto it is not working for me.

Comment: @Topaco I think the `spki` solved it for me. Thank you.

Comment: React is just JS. Using `alert(crypto)` results in `[object Crypto]` on Firefox for me.

Comment: @ChrisG I think you are right. I am wondering what I did wrong before, but I am happy that it works anyway now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Topaco mentioned to use a public key I has to use the `spki` format. That solves the issue with the import of the public key.
This code solves my problem.

```
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}

function importRsaPublicKey(pem) {

    const binaryDerString = atob(pem);
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "spki",
        binaryDer,
        {
            name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
            hash: "SHA-256",
        },
        true,
        ["verify"]
    );
}
```

I used the `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` algorithm as it doesn't require a salt.

Comment: Kudos for sharing the solution to your problem. This is the way! :-)

Comment: And a nice welcome for this. +1